# Be $K$ a normed vector space. If $A \subset K$ is compact and $p \in K$, prove that $A_p = \{x+p:x \in A\} $ is also compact.

Tags: proof-explanation, compactness, normed-spaces

Be $E$ a normed vector space. If $A \subset E$ is compact and $p \in E$, prove that $A_p = \{x+p:x \in A\} $ is also compact.

Hello, everyone! All right? I tried to prove this exercise, but I believe my demonstration is not correct. Could someone tell me what theorem I use to make this demonstration?

Comment: You don't need any theorems, just the definition of compactness and the fact that if $U\subseteq K$ is open, then so is $U_p$.

Comment: Hint: The translation map $x \mapsto p+a$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{U_n\}$ be an open coverage of $A_p$. Let $t: x \mapsto x+p$ be the translation map, which is a homeomorphism. So $\{t^{-1}(U_n)\}$ is an open coverage of $A$. Since $A$ is compact there is a finite subcoverage ${\{t^{-1}(U_{n_1}),...,t^{-1}(U_{n_k})\}}$. For this reason ${\{U_{n_1},...,U_{n_k}\}}$ covers $A_p$.

Comment: #Luca.b Is it possible to demonstrate without using cover?

Comment: This is the standard proof that the image of a compact through a continuos map is compact. You can prove it also using some alternative definitions of compactness, that are equivalent to compactness in a metric space. For example you can show that  $A_p$ is sequentially compact. If $\{y_n\}$ is a sequence in $A_p$ then since $t$ is surjective $y_n=t(x_n)\ $. $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $A$, which is compact, so it has a convergent subsequence, $\{x_{n_j}\}$. By continuity $\{y_{n_j}\}$ is a convergent subsequence of $\{y_{n}\} \Rightarrow A_p \ compact$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $p$, the translation $T: \>x\mapsto x+p$ of $K$ is bijective and continuous, and so is $T^{-1}: \>x\mapsto x-p$. It follows that $T$ is a homeomorphism of $K$. This implies that the image of a compact set $A$ is again compact.